# Adding up 'ord' values from user input

Tags: python, pycharm

I am trying to add the character value of the ord function, from a user input. I am able to get it to print out the value of each letter but I am stuck on adding up the entire value for the word the user inputs.

Here is what I have so far:

def main():

```
key_word = "quit"
word = ""

while word != key_word:
    word = input(str("Enter a word: "))
    word = word.lower()
    for letter in word:
        value = ord(letter)
        character = value - 96
        print(character)
if word == key_word:
    print(end="")
```

main()

Comment: You will need a way to keep track as you examine each individual letter. Remember that you can create new variables in any level. Where they are created and accessible is called "scope" https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for the sum of the ord values?

If so:

```
key_word = "quit"
word = ""
total = 0

while word != key_word:
    word = input(str("Enter a word: "))
    word = word.lower()
    for letter in word:
        value = ord(letter)
        total += ord(letter)
        character = value - 96
        print(character)

if word == key_word:
    print(end="")
    print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want adds up the value of each letter of the word :

```
while word != key_word:
    word = input(str("Enter a word: "))
    word = word.lower()
    word_value = 0
    for letter in word:
        value = ord(letter)
        character = value - 96
        word_value += character
        print(character)
    print('Total word value', word_value)
if word == key_word:
    print(end="")
```